# Expanding the power of a sum

Tags: probability, summation

I was reading *Probability Theory* by Borovkov when I was stuck on this expansion in the Proof of the Law of Large numbers for the Bernoulli Scheme. Note that the $\xi_j$'s are independent Bernoulli random variables with $p$ probability of success.
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j=1}^k(\xi_j-p)\right)^4 = \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j=1}^k(\xi_j-p)^4 + 6\sum_{i<j}(\xi_i-p)^2(\xi_j-p)^2\right)$$
I'm not sure how to go about showing this. I tried to look at the multinomial theorem but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Note that any term that winds up with a factor like $(\xi-p)$ has expectation $0$ since $E[\xi]=p$.

Comment: Second hint:  the only terms in $(a+b+c+\cdots)^4$ that don't have a factor with exponent $1$ are terms like $a^4$ or like $a^2b^2$.  Should say:  I am reading the left hand as $E\left[ \left(\sum (\cdots)\right)^4\right]$.  I think the way you wrote it is ambiguous.

Comment: @lulu I see it now, thanks